# Action Link with Dialogflow returns blank intent in the Actions Console

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to integrate Actions Links. I created two intents in Dialogflow: `product.user.order` and `product.user.price`. These are both deep link as can be seen here:
[image]

In the Actions Console, under Deploy -> Action Links, I want to set the `user.product.price` intent to generate a URL to deep link users into a specific action. When I select the intent, it says: *Action Links are not enabled for this intent in nl language. You can enable it here.*[image]

So after clicking the link I'm routed to Develop -> Actions -> my intent. At the top it says *Dutch* and when I try to modify the languages it is Dutch as well. My Dialogflow agent is Dutch as well and uses the code *Dutch - nl*. After confirming the languages are both Dutch I set the 'Links' tab of the intent to true by switching the button. This generated a URL for the intent with the specified Link title, as can be seen here:

```
<a href="https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/<myuuid>?intent=user.product.price&hl=nl">
     Ask <projectname> to retrieve the price
</a>
```

After return to Deploy -> Action Links in the Actions Console, I want to generate a URL to deep link users. Suddenly two blank options are created:

[image]

Both blank options are created after enabling the links in the Develop section. They also generate a url in the following format: `https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uuid/<uuid>?intent&hl=nl`. This is incorrect, as there is no intent specified (which seems to straight forward as there is a blank option generated). The link obviously did not work as expected, after testing it.

When I select the `user.product.price` intent it will still say *Action Links are not enabled for this intent in nl language. You can enable it here.* This will route me to the same page and after retrying setting up the link it still returns a blank option.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you find solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the Actions Console that is generating these two blank intents.

That said, I think the link you're looking for is what you mention you get under `Develop -> Actions -> my intent` inside the HTML snippet.

i.e. `https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/<myuuid>?intent=user.product.price&hl=nl`

If you want you can add additional query params to this URL as mentioned in the official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/action-links#action_link_parameters).

Hope this helps.